# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier creates duplicate UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

[image: View I a creating]

I am creating a page where I am using UITableView and UITableViewCell. The above shown photo is one UITableViewCell created programatically.

This UITableViewCell is getting created in cellForRowAtIndexPath where i am using tags for views and reusing views with tags whenever cellForRowAtIndexPath is called

------------------- Code for cell creation ---------------------------

```
NSString* reuseIdentifier = @"NameNCityCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell withIndexPath: indexPath];
```

In this UITableViewCell when we tap on city , A new controller is opened where I can select city which will reflect in the City Column in current viewcontroller.

**Now The problem.**
when I open the page with this cell, new cell is created but after tapping on the citycontroller and selecting city it comes to this previous controller and instead of using the same cell, it creates new . So its like one cell over another (Duplicates)

Now I again tap on citycontroller and select city, on selection when it comes to this VC and it uses the hidden view from the 2 views.

I need to know How should I do that so that two view are not created. I want to work with the same view.

Let me now if you need more details.

Comment: You dont need the whole `if (nil == cell)....` part, remove it, for your problem, you should post the cell tapping handling function here

Comment: Then everytime a new cell gets created

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta can you show the code when selecting city and when tapping on the cell?

Comment: `configureCell:withIndexPath:` What the code for that method?

Answer (score 1):

```
    You are overwriting cell in a UItableview. Please use below simple 1 line of code.




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         YourtableViewCellName *cell = (YourtableViewCellName *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-1"]; //profilePic - image View
            cell.titleTV.text = @"Hi"; //Name
            cell.detailTV.text = @"How are you?"; //City
            return cell;
     }
```

Comment: To use this I have to register first? I am actually creating the view for cells in cellforrowatindex

Comment: You just need to create custom cell in Interface.Then you need to create custom cell with class. Set identifier for cell.

Comment: Renish Dadhaniya I want to do it programmatically not on xib's.

Comment: I have added code for Programmatically create cell. Please review basic of UITableView.  Here are some reference url - http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/customize-table-view-cells-uitableview-ios , https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Comment: Where have you added ?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom cell Class like example

```
#import "JSCustomCell.h"
@implementation JSCustomCell
@synthesize descriptionLabel = _descriptionLabel;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure control(s)
        self.descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 30)];
        self.descriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f];

        [self addSubview:self.descriptionLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then the main view controller

```
#import "JSViewController.h"
#import "JSCustomCell.h"
@interface JSViewController ()
@end
@implementation JSViewController {
    UITableView *tableView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // init table view
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    // must set delegate & dataSource, otherwise the the table will be empty and not responsive
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    // add to canvas
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
// number of section(s), now I assume there is only 1 section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
{
    return 1;
}
// number of row in the section, I assume there is only 1 row
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
// the cell will be returned to the tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but 
    JSCustomCell *cell = (JSCustomCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[JSCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // Just want to test, so I hardcode the data
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"Testing";

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
// when user tap the row, what action you want to perform
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected %d row", indexPath.row);
}
@end
```